# Using one struts 2 tag inside another

Tags: select, struts2

I have a struts 2 select element to select the mumber of results to be diplayed per page. I set the selected value in a session variable. On the JSP page I want the user selected value to be preselected in the select element. If I hard cord the value it works like this

```
<s:select name="fetchSize" cssClass="textCopmanyPropValue" value="20" headerKey="" list="#{'10':'10 Results/Page', '15':'15 Results/Page', '20' : '20 Results/Page', '25':'25 Results/Page'}"/>`
```

But if I use value from session using the `<s:property>` tag it doesn't work

```
<s:select name="fetchSize" cssClass="textCopmanyPropValue" value="<s:property value='%{#session.fetchSize}'/>" headerKey="" list="#{'10':'10 Results/Page', '15':'15 Results/Page', '20' : '20 Results/Page', '25':'25 Results/Page'}"/>`
```

Please help how can I work this out. And secondly, It is always so confusing when it comes to using one struts 2 tag inside another. Can somebody provide the sysntax how to use one struts 2 tag inside another.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A Struts tag will trigger a set of codes internally to be executed. A Struts tag inside another struts tag is not allowed. This is similar to HTML where you can't use a tag inside another tag. Instead, you might want to make `fetchSize` as a property/attribute/field in your action class, and fetch it directly inside your `select` tag i.e `value='fetchSize'`. Struts 2 will trigger a setter `getFetchSize()` on the `ActionContext`, so do not forget your getter/setter in your Action class.

Answer (score 0):

Get help from standard taglibs:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
...
<c:set var="fetchSize"><s:property value='%{#session.fetchSize}'/></c:set>
<s:select name="fetchSize" 
          cssClass="textCopmanyPropValue" 
          value="${fetchSize}" 
          headerKey="" 
          list="#{'10':'10 Results/Page', '15':'15 Results/Page', '20' : '20 Results/Page', '25':'25 Results/Page'}"/>`
```

Not very elegant, but functional.